# Error writing data to pki/issue/vault-server: common name not allowed by this role

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

When migrating the vault fqdn from `vault.**.**.**.abc.com` to `vault.**.**.**.def.com`. Hit this error. Already created the CNAME in route53 and the domain can be resolved.

````
URL: PUT https://ap-ops-vault.***.com/v1/pki/issue/vault-server
Code: 400. Errors:

 * common name vault.**.**.**.def.com not allowed by this role```
````

Comment: Looks like an AWS IAM role limitation - from where are you attempting to execute this request?

Comment: So the deployment was carried from a server living in another account. The IAM role as full ec2 access, full vpc access, full route 53 access, access to s3 bucket that store vault environment state, access to assume IAM role in other accounts, and access to ssm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your Vault role configuration, I would guess that you have the `allowed_domains` field set, with `abc.com` included but not `def.com`. You will need to update the role to allow names from the new domain.

Probably something like this in Terraform:

```
resource "vault_pki_secret_backend_role" "role" {
  backend = "${vault_pki_secret_backend.pki.path}"
  name    = "my_role"
  ...
  allowed_domains = ["abc.com", "def.com"]
  allow_subdomains = true
  ...
}
```

Docs:

- https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/pki#allowed_domains
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vault/r/pki_secret_backend_role.html#allowed_domains

Comment: I have tried this: `vault write pki/issue/vault-server enforce_hostnames=false common_name=vault.**.**.**.def.com`.  It gives me the same error. 


What's even more confusing is that using the original domain `abc.com` will make this write operation go through (whether to set the enforce true or false). The old domain name has been removed and the CNAME is no longer valid, I don't understand this behavior

Comment: The `enforce_hostnames` parameter isn't set like that - you need to use it to configure the role that you are using. If using `vault.**.**.**.abc.com` works, then it might be that your role has the `allowed_domains` field set (https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/pki#allowed_domains) - you will need to update that list to include the new domain

Comment: I've just updated my answer to instead suggest looking at `allowed_domains`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The problem is solved by adding the new domain into the allowed_domains field set.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to upvote and accept this answer if it solves your problem